# Запись в вектор объектов класса из файла

Tags: c++, c, vector

После считывания в векторе получаются одни и те же значения. Не понимаю в чем причина. Если выводить tempVar1 в цикле то в нем правильные значения, но в итоге в векторе одни и те же.

```
class Edge{
 //
}

void ReadFromFile(vector<Vertex*>& vertexs, vector<Edge*>& edges) {
        char buff[20];
        vector<string> buffer;
        bool flag = 0;
        fstream fin;
        fin.open("test.tgf", ios::in);
        while (!fin.eof()) {
            fin.getline(buff, 20);
            if (buff[0] == '#') {
                flag = 1;
                continue;
            }
            if (flag == 0) {
                buffer = Split(buff, " ");
                //Vertex tempVar(atoi(buffer[0].c_str()), buffer[1].c_str());
                //vertexs.push_back(&tempVar);
            }
            if (flag == 1) {
                buffer = Split(buff, " ");
                Edge tempVar1(atoi(buffer[0].c_str()), atoi(buffer[1].c_str()), atoi(buffer[2].c_str()));
                edges.push_back(&tempVar1);
            }
        }
        fin.close();
```

В векторе получаются такие значения:

```
6 4 1
6 4 1
6 4 1
6 4 1
6 4 1
6 4 1
6 4 1
6 4 1
6 4 1
6 4 1
6 4 1
```

Вместо:

```
1 2 1
1 5 1
2 5 1
5 4 1
2 3 1
3 4 1
4 6 1
2 1 1
5 1 1
5 2 1
4 5 1
3 2 1
4 3 1
6 4 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  ...
  Edge* tempVar1 = new Edge(atoi(buffer[0].c_str()), atoi(buffer[1].c_str()), atoi(buffer[2].c_str()));
  edges.push_back(tempVar1);
}
```

Comment: согласен, что автор пытался хранить адреса временных обьектов, но  
это не поможет устранить другие ошибки...